# Como fazer links com preventDefault no angular?

Tags: angularjs, link

Estou usando uma função chamada com `ng-click`, através de um link (Âncora).
Porém, por conta do hash `#`, a página está "pulando" toda vez que clico nesse link.

O meu código é esse:

```
<a ng-click="openImageModal(request)" href="#">
   Abrir modal
</a>
```

Gostaria de fazer um `preventDefault` nesse link, para que ele executasse a função do `angularjs`, porém sem "pular" a página, por causa do hash `#`.

Como fazer isso no `AngularJS`?

Gostaria de uma solução **sem usar jQuery**, pois quero me desvencilhar da dependência dele.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Remova `href='#'`
- adicione a seguinte classe CSS:

  ```
  a[ng-click]{
      cursor: pointer;
  }
  ```

Assim você eliminará o comportamento padrão, mantendo o feedback visual do link.

Comment: E o `.directive`?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento você diz na declaração de classe ou na definição da diretiva?

Comment: não entendo de Angular.js, mas acredito que seja no contexto do `angular.module`. Vou tentar fazer, apesar que a sua resposta sem removendo o `href="#"` já funcionou perfeitamente, menos código menos manutenção xD (meu +1 já estava garantido).

Answer (score 4):

Altere o `href="#"` para `href="javascript:void(0)"`.

Answer (score 4):

Se você definir o `href` vazio também funcionará:

```
<a href ng-click="addNinja('OnoSedai')">Adicionar Novo Ninja</a>
```

A vantagem de fazer assim é que você não vai precisar definir um CSS por causa da ausência `cursor:pointer`, já que links sem `href` *em alguns navegadores* não vêm com `cursor:pointer` por padrão.

Veja funcionando no Ideone:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/7523/

Comment: Precisa do `href` vazio? Sei que sem angular ele é necessário, pois se não o browser não renderiza como link, todavia não sei o efeito no angular

Comment: Testei aqui, o `href` vazio é dispensavel http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/7524/ também, basta fazer `<a ng-click="addNinja('onoSedai')">Teste</a>`, +1 pela descoberta ;)

Comment: Mas o problema é o **cursor:pointer** @GuilhermeNascimento, com `href` vazio nem preciso definir um css para isso :D

Comment: Aqui sem o href o cursor aparece normalmente, tanto com href como sem.

Comment: Mas no bootstrap não.

Comment: A aparição ou não do cursor é dependente do browser. A classe CSS na minha resposta é usada para forçar o comportamento.

Comment: @OnoSendai vou marcar sua resposta :). O Dom ficará mais limpo.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters *domo!*

Comment: Bootstrap não influenciou até aonde testei http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/7525/

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento deve ser o google chrome então. Eu estou usando a classe "thumbnail" e está dando diferença. Vou fazer um fiddle

Comment: @WallaceMaxters entendi, deve depender do conteudo, melhor manter o `href`